# Populate a Textbox in Access 2016 from Combobox and Listbox Selection

Tags: ms-access

I have a form with a combobox that allows user to select a single company. When they select the company, a listbox is populated with a list of groups for that company. When the user selects a group in the listbox, I want to populate one textbox with the MAX(Order_Date) from a table where the CustomerID field is equal to the cboCustomers selected value and the [Nat'l Accounts] field is equal to the selected group from the listbox. I just basically want this query result to populate a textbox.

```
    select MAX([Quote Date])
    from quotes 
    where customerid=cboCustomers 
    and [Nat'l Accounts]=cboNationalAccounts
```

Below is my control source query on the textbox.

```
=DLookUp(Max([Quote Date]),[Quotes],[Quotes]![CustomerID]=[cboCustomers] & [Quotes]![Nat'l Accounts]=[cboNatlAccounts])
```

In the after update event of the listbox, I have

```
    Private Sub cboNatlAccounts_AfterUpdate()
        QuoteDate_Textbox.Visible = True
        QuoteDate_Label.Visible = True
        QuoteDate_Textbox.Requery
    End Sub
```

When I run the form, the listbox populates successfully. When I select a record in the listbox the two controls (label & textbox) do become visible, but the textbox shows #Name?.

How do I populate a textbox with the max date for the company and group?

Comment: Already have Max([Quote Date]) in combobox - why do you also need it in textbox? Why a combobox if only one item is listed? DLookup() syntax is wrong. Arguments need to be within quote marks unless they are declared VBA variables or form controls. DLookup appears to be wrong argument anyway, try DMax. You have [cboNationalAccounts] and [cboNatlAccounts] - which is correct? Simplify life and don't use spaces or punctuation/special characters in naming convention.

Comment: Well, unfortunately, I inherited this database and it has lots of issues. Let me try modifying the DLookup syntax.

Comment: Still unclear why you are using textbox with domain aggregate when data is already in listbox.

Comment: Let me try to clarify this scenario. There is a table called [Quotes] that contains a [QuoteID], [CustomerID], [Nat'l Accounts], and [Quote Date] fields. There can be multiple quotes for the same customer for different 'Nat'l Accounts' and quote dates.

Comment: The user selects a customer from a dropdown which populates a listbox showing each Nat'l Account and includes the CustomerID and MAX([Quote Date]). I have a textbox populating successfully with the CustomerID and another one with the Max(Order Date). (to be continued)

Comment: I am trying to populate a textbox with the OrderID that corresponds to the selected Nat'l Account/Max(Order Date). The reason for getting the OrderID is the next step will be to duplicate the selected Quote for the Customer/Nat'l Account/Max(Order Date) and create a new identical quote for them using the current date.

Hopefully, this clarifies what I'm trying to do a bit.

This is the ControlSource of the textbox I am trying to populate:
DLookup("[QuoteID]","[Quotes]","[Quote Date]=" & [QuoteDate_Textbox] & " AND [Nat'l Accounts]='" & [cboNatlAccounts] & "'" )

(to be continued)

Comment: When I run the form with the above in the Control Source, the textbox just shows:
#Error

Comment: Date/time type fields need # delimiter around input. `"[Quote Date]=#" & [QuoteDate_Textbox] & "# AND`.

Comment: Oh good heavens - that was the problem. I've been in SQL Server for probably 15 years before I got this Access project. I had completely forgotten the # surround dates!